# How to change host from localhost to my network ip in vue-storefront?

Tags: magento2, localhost, npm, vue-storefront, yarn

I have install Vue-storefront in my local machine(Ubuntu 18) by following these commands

> git clone https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront.git vue-storefront
>
> cd vue-storefront
>
> yarn
>
> yarn installer

here I have used https://demo.vuestorefront.io as the backend
I have install vue-storefront successfully

[image: vue-storefront]

in localhost:3000

but I want to change **localhost** to **192.168.0.172** and port **3000** to **8080**

for this, I have made changes in vue-storefront/config/local.json

[image: vue-storefront/config/local.json]

I have run

> npm restart

But I can not access this http://192.168.0.172:8080/

How can I do this...

Comment: what is the error when you hit http://192.168.0.172:8080/ ?

Comment: @RizwanKhan 404

Comment: which OS you are using, also if you are in network make sure http://192.168.0.172/ will point to your system.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, I have properly configured my network IP

Comment: can you run `yarn dev` instead of `npm restart` and check once.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `192.168.0.172 localhost` in `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for development is:

`"host": "0.0.0.0"`

This makes server listening from localhost and remote connections. For example I was trying to develop storefront on remote server and I was not able to reach app through my domain name (for example: "myawesomedomain.com" with `"host: "myawesomedomain.com"` will not work)

Of course... there can be some security problems :-)